# Java when making new folder, its unusable

Tags: java

I am trying to make a new folder to save an image to. The program makes a file instead of a folder, and the file is not accessible (which makes sense since it has no suffix).

[image: picture of the folder after creation]

Code:

```
public class Main
 {
    public BufferedImage img = null;
    public String outPath;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

       System.out.println("enter out put path like c:\\test: ");
        outPath = scan.nextLine();

        makeDir();
        writeFile();

    }

     public void makeDir()
    {

        // Create one directory
        boolean success = (new File(outPath)).mkdir();
        if (success)
        {
            System.out.println("Directory: " + outPath + " created");
        }
    }

    public void writeFile()
    {
        try
        {
            File f = new File(outPath);
            ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", f);
            System.out.println("finished writing: " + outPath);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: I'm going to remove the `makefile` tag, as it seems to being misused here.

Comment: And what does "unusable" mean?

Comment: And "however its unusable" isn't very helpful. Please fully describe your problem.

Comment: 1- it makes a file instead of a folder, and the file is not accessible (which makes sense since it has no suffix).

Comment: can you show the main method too?

Comment: added main and where path comes from

Comment: Please post a [mcve], that's too much code to create a folder

Comment: For code readability please adhere to the 'standard' Java code guidelines, thus methods starting with lowercase.

Comment: I can see a method called `MakeDir` but I can't see any code that actually calls it. Please add that code (and remove the duplicate code "sample" which is not the code you are actually running and is therefore irrelevant).

Comment: Sigh. Instead of giving pieces of code from the `main` without context and without us knowing what the path is, what you are trying to do, etc., please create a [mcve], which we can all run on our own computer and see your problem.

Comment: Done, all the requests have been  implemented in the question.

Comment: I tried it and it worked for me. First of all do not give pseudo code , this code does not even compile. using non static variables in static method, scan not declared and so on ..., Could you post your actual code, so we can have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing the file to the same filename as the directory you create. Can you add a filename for the image, like

```
File f = new File(outPath);
File imageFile = new File(f, "image.jpg")
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", imageFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you that `mkdir()` and `mkdirs()` work perfectly fine and that the flaw is likely to be in the program's flow.

If there is already a directory or a file with the same path the directory will not be created.

You can check this by using `exists()`, which will return `true` if there is a file or directory with that path. If you want to know if the path is a file or a directory you can use `isFile()` and `isDirectory()` to determine the type.

Comment: I do believe mkdir() works fine, however i have a logic error somewhere in the code that is making it behave like this. i am sure the folder name i am giving it does not already exist.

Comment: Exactly, therefore include System.out.println(...) steps in between using the exists() just prior to your mkdir() call. Or, just use your IDE's standard debugger.

Comment: I did, the compiler does reach the location correctly, i am also reading from a folder in that location and reading works fine.